# listview not display after changing orientation

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I Have listview in my xml file. Below listview I have other layouts. If I set android:layout_weight="1" in listview then after changing orientation it does not scroll and only layout below listview is visible . If I remove layout_weight="1" from listview then without changing orientation also listview is not visible. Here is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/applogo"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@layout/header_gradient" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/beforelogo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="46dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="141dp"
        android:layout_height="46dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@drawable/logo" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/afterlogo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/beforelogo"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/logout" />
</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="15dip" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.45"
        android:text="CASH BILL"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.45"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:inputType="datetime" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/calendar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:src="@drawable/calendar" />
</LinearLayout>

<View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/cash_bill_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/other_charges_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/cash_bill_list"
        android:padding="2dp" >

        <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/other_charges_txt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Other Charges"
            android:textSize="@dimen/rating" />

        <!-- day open -->

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/other_charges"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/other_charges_txt"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text=""
            android:textSize="@dimen/rating" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/security_tax_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/other_charges_layout"
        android:padding="2dp" >

        <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/security_tax_txt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Security Tr. T"
            android:textSize="@dimen/rating" />

        <!-- day open -->

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/security_tax"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/security_tax_txt"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text=""
            android:textSize="@dimen/rating" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/serice_tax_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/security_tax_layout"
        android:padding="2dp" >

        <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/serice_tax_txt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Service Tax"
            android:textSize="@dimen/rating" />

        <!-- day open -->

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/serice_tax"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/serice_tax_txt"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text=""
            android:textSize="@dimen/rating" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/stamp_duty_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/serice_tax_layout"
        android:padding="2dp" >

        <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/stamp_duty_txt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Stamp Duty"
            android:textSize="@dimen/rating" />

        <!-- day open -->

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/stamp_duty"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/stamp_duty_txt"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text=""
            android:textSize="@dimen/rating" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/due_to_you_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/stamp_duty_layout"
        android:padding="2dp" >

        <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/total_txt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Total"
            android:textSize="@dimen/rating" />

        <!-- day open -->

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/total"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/total_txt"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text=""
            android:textSize="@dimen/rating" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

What should I do so listview is visible and after changing orientation scroll is also available. Thanks in advance

Comment: what is your orientation in the xml file? Because if you have a LinearLayout with the horizntal orientation, it might be pushed out of the screen

Comment: No orientation is vertical. I had added my xml in question.

Comment: I edit the code, I forgot to add the first element in the scrollview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is my result. I think you should let the list view be 1/2 of the screen and with the rest of the elements add them a ScrollView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical">

<!-- HEADER -->

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/applogo"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/RedishColor">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/beforelogo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="46dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="141dp"
        android:layout_height="46dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@color/GreenSeaColor" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/afterlogo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/beforelogo"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/view_icon" />
</RelativeLayout>

<!-- TOP BAR -->

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="15dip">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.45"
        android:text="CASH BILL"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.45"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:inputType="datetime" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/calendar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="0.1" />
</LinearLayout>

<View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

<!-- LISTVIEW -->
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/cash_bill_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.1" />

    <!-- BOTTOM PART -->

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.1">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/other_charges_layout"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/cash_bill_list"
                android:padding="2dp">

                <View
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/other_charges_txt"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="Other Charges"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <!-- day open -->

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/other_charges"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/other_charges_txt"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textSize="20sp" />
            </RelativeLayout>


            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/security_tax_layout"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/other_charges_layout"
                android:padding="2dp">

                <View
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/security_tax_txt"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="Security Tr. T"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <!-- day open -->

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/security_tax"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/security_tax_txt"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textSize="20sp" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/serice_tax_layout"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/security_tax_layout"
                android:padding="2dp">

                <View
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/serice_tax_txt"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="Service Tax"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <!-- day open -->

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/serice_tax"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/serice_tax_txt"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textSize="20sp" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/stamp_duty_layout"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/serice_tax_layout"
                android:padding="2dp">

                <View
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/stamp_duty_txt"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="Stamp Duty"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <!-- day open -->

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/stamp_duty"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/stamp_duty_txt"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textSize="20sp" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/due_to_you_layout"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/stamp_duty_layout"
                android:padding="2dp">

                <View
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/total_txt"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="Total"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <!-- day open -->

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/total"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/total_txt"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textSize="20sp" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Result Images:

VERTICAL

[image]

HORZIONTAL

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a `</LinearLayout>`. I do not know if this will solve the problem. Also usually if you add the weight attribute you would add it to the other elements in that LinearLayout so that the layout can weight all the elements properly. By adding just the weight attribute, the other elements may by getting a 0 weight by default and hence would not be shown.