# Android Listview Doesn't show anything when changing orientation

Tags: android, listview, xamarin, orientation

I'm using the listview in xamarin android. When I run the app the listview is showing data perfectly but, if I change the orientation my listview isn't showing anything. My listview's location is middle of the page. When I change orientation it's staying under of the page. I tried to use scroll view but it doesn't change anything

Comment: add this `android:configChanges="orientation`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya You should avoid using of `android:configChanges="orientation"`. For more details see [Bad Practice: Retain the Activity](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html#bad-practice-retain-the-activity)

Comment: @matoni thanks for info .

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26627516/listview-not-display-after-changing-orientation

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya thanks but it didn't work for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved the problem with scrollview in layout and nestedScrollingEnabled=true in my listview. thanks everybody